# asp.net mvc, how to prevent session overriding

Tags: asp.net, session

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSessionValue(string enteredNumber)
        {
            Session["number"] = enteredNumber;
            return View();
        }
```

EnterNumber.html:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="enteredNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="GetSessionValue">
</form>
```

GetSessionValue.html:

```
@Session["number"]
```

If I provide number 20, it prints as follows:

```
20
```

Cool. Now I enter 100 and expect to see this:

```
20
100
```

But instead I see this:

```
100
```

So the first value is lost. So, how to prevent this to happen? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple sessions in a browser. You can store arrays inside of the session array though.

This is your best option to achieve that.

```
Session[enteredNumber] = "Here is your new session" ;
```

From there you can modify what is in that "session".

Comment: sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. i don't want an array. i want different sessions.

Comment: thanks, eeerrm...mind to elaborate a bit? not quite clear with this example.